# How can I see all @deprecated code in my whole project in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to see all references in my project which is deprecated. At this moment if I need to find out if there is something deprecated, I need to go through all the files and see if there is any deprecated code there.

Comment: Any particular programming lanugage you are interested in? If for JS/TS, see [Is there an extension of CLI command to find all deprecated methods used in a project?](/q/68760282)

Comment: for Python, you can make deprecations into problems and then see them all in the Problems Panel (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76889783/11107541))