# How can I make VS Code treat usage of deprecated things in Python code as Problems?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, deprecated, pylance

Is there any way to see at a glance (in the Problem tab for example) all the deprecated methods I used in my project using Visual Studio Code?

[image]

[image]

I use Pylance, but the extension just crosses out the word and I expect see all this warnings inside Problems tab

Comment: How did you even manage to make VSCode cross out the event.dict() method? I'm trying with warnings.warn but VSCode is not "catching" it.

Comment: @kle10 They've done it using the `typing_extensions.deprecated` decorator. You can see the source code their using [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/4dd40aec7397418e37b1029a0496b486adecbb7c/pydantic/main.py#L1129). Eventually the decorator will be in the `warnings` module, see [PEP 702](https://peps.python.org/pep-0702/).

Pylance detects it's usage and adds the strikethrough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I asked about this](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/discussions/4713#discussion-5512873) and [the maintainers of Pylance replied](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/discussions/4713#discussioncomment-6706910) that the Pylance extension for VS Code (part of the Python extension pack) already supports this through its support for Pyright. You can create a pyrightconfig.json file in the root of your workspace folder (if you don't have one already) and use the [`reportDeprecated`](https://microsoft.github.io/pyright/#/configuration?id=diagnostic-rule-defaults:%7E:text=reportDeprecated%20%5Bboolean%20or%20string%2C%20optional%5D) property, which can take a boolean or a string for a problem type/level to report it as: `"information"`, `"warning"`, or `"error"`.

See also the `pylint.severity` setting (example usage shown in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-april-2022-release/#pylint-extension).

Answer (score 1):

Creating a "pyrightconfig.json" in the root of your project and set

```
{
    "reportDeprecated": "warning"
}
```

in the file, should work

[image]