# How can I extract the deprecated def using pyrightconfig.json with Visual Studio Code's Pylance?

Tags: python-3.x, pylance, pyright

I'm currently trying to detect deprecated defs in Visual Studio Code's Pylance, as shown in the article below.

[How can I make VS Code treat usage of deprecated things in Python code as Problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883362/how-can-i-make-vs-code-treat-usage-of-deprecated-things-in-python-code-as-proble)

I set pyrightconfig.json in the root of the project with the following content, but it doesn't work.

```
{
    "reportDeprecated": "warning"
}
```

for exsample, deprecated def in python code is:

```py
logging.warn('exsample')
```

*Python* → *Analysis: Type Checking Mode* is 'standard', in Visual Studio Code.

What can I do to fix it?

I hope the check can successfully detect deprecated defs.

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not screenshot.

Comment: What is deprecated in your example?